# How to stop the redirecting after payment confirm on stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to store the customer order at MongoDB once the user confirms payment. So how can i stop the redirecting in stripe after confirm payment?

Comment: What API are you using?  What is the payment flow you are basing your approach on?  Can you point to something in the public Stripe docs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 15):

The `if_required` flag does not trigger automatic redirect to the `return_url`. Therefore you can handle your redirect logic by invoking the `handleSuccess` or `handleError` methods appropriately, as shown below:

```js
try {
  const { error, paymentIntent } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: "https://google.com",
    },
    redirect: "if_required",
  });
  
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    // handleError();
  } else if (paymentIntent && paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
    console.log("Payment succeeded");
    // handleSuccess();
  } else {
    console.log("Payment failed");
    // handleOther();
  }
  } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use default param from documentation  https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-redirect

```
confirmParams: {
    return_url: "https://example.com",
},
    redirect: 'if_required' 
});
```